# Glossary will not not be displayed (however I try)

Tags: pdf, compiling, glossaries

So the weirdest thing ever happened. I set up a template, it worked all fine and dandy. And then I reload the document some days later, and everything is white. For no reason I could find, my glossary will not show up (no matter what I try). I tried to reduce everything to a bare minimun, still get a PDF without a glossary. It's not supposed to work like this, but for the life of me I cannot find the reason why it does this.

I have two files, one with glossary entries, and one which is supposed to display all these.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym,toc,style=altlist]{glossaries}

\include{Glossar}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Some text

\printglossary
\glsaddallunused
\end{document}
```

And the glossary with entries like these:

```
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\longnewglossaryentry{fishage}
{name={Fish Age}}
{%
A common name for the Devonian geologic period
spanning from the end of the Silurian Period to
the beginning of the Carboniferous Period.
This age was known for its remarkable variety of
fish species.
}
```

Code couldn't get simpler than this I thought, but still haven't found the mistake. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this setup: put `\makeglossaries` in you preamble and then load the glossaries list using `\loadglsentries{<file name>}`

Then compile twice + run makeglossaries.exe + compile again to make the list appear.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym,toc,style=altlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries % in the main document

\loadglsentries{gloss_list} % load glossaries

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    Some text
    
    \printglossary
    \glsaddallunused
\end{document}
```

with `gloss_list.tex`

```
\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\longnewglossaryentry{fishage}
{name={Fish Age}}
{%
    A common name for the Devonian geologic period
    spanning from the end of the Silurian Period to
    the beginning of the Carboniferous Period.
    This age was known for its remarkable variety of
    fish species.
}
```